# Create an Instance of Polymer Element in Dart, which is not a HtmlElement

Tags: dart, polymer

I have a PolymerElement called NewEntryElement, and I want it to be created and added if a Button is clicked.

new-Entry.html

```
<polymer-element name="new-Entry" attributes="metaData">
  <!-- a table here -->
</polymer-element>
```

new-Entry.dart

```
@CustomTag('new-entry')
class NewEntryElement extends PolymerElement {
  @published List<Map> metaData;

  factory NewEntryElement() => document.createElement("new-entry");

  NewEntryElement.created() : super.created() {
    polymerCreated();
  }
}
```

Calling the factory in my button function does not work, since a HtmlElement is created and it can't be cast to NewEntryElement. So i also tried to call this in my Button function:

```
var newEntry = new Element.tag('new-entry');
(newEntry as NewEntryElement).metaData = this.metaData;
```

There is the same Problem... So I need a way to get an Instance of my PolymerElement so i can assign the attribute metaData to the Element.

Btw: this is the Exception:

```
Exception: Uncaught Error: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'NewEntryElement' in type cast.
```

Comment: When you load the app in Dartium, do you see errors/warnings in the bottom-right corner of the browser window? Does the browser console show some errors/warnings? What Dart/Polymer version are you using?
You should use all-lowercase file names and only underscore instead of dash according to Dart style guide. It is more probably to run into bugs if your code/files don't comply with the style rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally works without problems. There seems to be something wrong with your polymer initialization code or element imports.

You have named your element `"new-Entry"` in HTML but use `"new-entry"` in code (upper-/lower-case `e`) this is probably what causes the problem.

Comment: And i also forgot the <script> tag, cant believe I searched 1,5h for an answer and only made such a silly mistake...

Comment: I like the `pub run polymer:new_element new-entry -o lib/components` command line command to create polymer elements a lot. It helps to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Since I use "Dart Editor" I dont have a command line.

Comment: The operating system provides the command line ;-). WebStorm has an integrated terminal which is nice but you can do it without any IDE.